# What's the correct way to provide default values for Laravel model fields outside of MySQL?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a Laravel model which has various fields that default to NULL in the database and cannot easily be changed for legacy reasons. I would like to always return these as an empty string, for example, when returning JSON back from my route. Is there a "standard" way to define defaults in a model somehow?

Another case might be that a certain field always needs some processing done on it before being returned, can this also be defined in a similar way? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Default values

You can specify default values with the `$attributes` property:

```
class MyModel extends Eloquent {
    protected $attributes = array(
        'foo' => 'bar'
    );
}
```

However I think this will still be overwritten by the `NULL` from the db. The use case for `$attributes` is rather when creating and inserting new records.

### Manipulating JSON / array output

To change your model before it is converted to JSON / into an array you can override `toArray()` in your model:

```
public function toArray(){
    $array = parent::toArray();
    foreach($array as &$value){
        if($value == null){
            $value = '';
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

### Custom attributes with accessors

If you have certain fields that require special kind of processing (e.g. formatting a date, concatenating two attributes) you can use an [accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators):

```
public function getFullNameAttribute(){
    return $this->attributes['firstname'].' '.$this->attributes['lastname'];
}
```

Now you can access it by `$model->full_name` (or `$model->fullName` whichever you prefer)

And finally, to add it to the JSON / array output, use `$appends`

```
protected $appends = array('full_name');
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Some combination of these should solve my problem.